# Проблема с namespace

Tags: php, namespace

Код one.php

```
<?php
namespace one;
use two\Two;

class One{
    function show_message($text){
        print("Тут какой то текст: $text");
    }
}
$one = new One();
$two = new Two();
$one->show_message($two->return_text());
```

Код two.php

```
<?php
namespace two;

class Two{
    function return_text(){
        return "А это у нас секретный текст";
    }
}
```

На выходе выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'two\Two' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\one.php:12 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\one.php on line 12

Без использования `namespace` все нормально(с помощью `include` или `require`). Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Comment: Почему бы не подключить класс Two через require??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы решить вашу проблему надо использовать [автозагрузку классов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.autoload.php).
Можно свалить эту задачу на [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) *(я ленивый, поэтому выбираю этот вариант)*.

Пространства имён не отменяют необходимости подключать файлы с классами.
Как следует из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.rationale.php), они решают такие проблемы:

1. Конфликт имен между вашим кодом и внутренними классами/функциями/константами PHP или сторонними.
2. Возможность создавать псевдонимы (или сокращения) для Ну_Очень_Длинных_Имен, чтобы облегчить первую проблему и улучшить читаемость исходного кода.